# In apache, is it possible to configure digest authentication to to add an authenticated username cookie to proxied requests?

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, digest, soap

I have digest authentication configured for a VirtualHost which proxies SOAP requests.  I would like my SOAP service to be able to know reliably which user is accessing it -- is there a way to configure apache to pass through the authenticated username as a cookie?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you cannot but, in any case, you do not need such a cookie.

You can find all the info you need inside http "Authorization" request header. Any web server should set this header (apache does it).

See: section 14.8 of [RFC 2068](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt).